# How to realize a circle image button with react native

Tags: react-native

There.
When I was trying to make a circle shaped button component with React Native. I set the borderRadius of an Image half the value of its height and width to make it looks like the circle button and apply gesture responder to it.As a result when i tapped outside the circle but inside some rectangular area around the Image view, the responder event dispatched which is unexpected.

I just cannot figure it out:

Is there any possibility to determine the touch area of Touchable* and how?
Does the gesture responder system support certain area gesture detection? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 95):

try this:

```js
 <TouchableOpacity
   style={{
       borderWidth:1,
       borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
       alignItems:'center',
       justifyContent:'center',
       width:100,
       height:100,
       backgroundColor:'#fff',
       borderRadius:50,
     }}
 >
   <Icon name={"chevron-right"}  size={30} color="#01a699" />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Does this have a demo?

Comment: Icon above is from https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: borderRadius should be half of the height(or width), more than that will create the same.

Answer (score 19):

You need to apply styling to the Touchable area as well as the image if you do not want the outside of the image to be touchable.

The first image has only the image Touchable, while the second only styles the image, leaving the entire rectangle touchable.

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text style={{ fontSize:22 }}>Only image clickable</Text>
       <TouchableHighlight style={ styles.imageContainer }>
            <Image style={ styles.image } source={{ uri: 'http://www.free-avatars.com/data/media/37/cat_avatar_0597.jpg' }} />
       </TouchableHighlight> 
       <Text style={{ fontSize:22 }}>Entire Row Clickable</Text>
       <TouchableHighlight style={ styles.imageContainer2 }>
            <Image style={ styles.image } source={{ uri: 'http://www.free-avatars.com/data/media/37/cat_avatar_0597.jpg' }} />
       </TouchableHighlight> 
      </View>  
    );
  }
}); 

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:60
  },
  imageContainer: {
    height:128,
    width: 128,
    borderRadius: 64
  },
  image: {
    height:128,
    width: 128,
    borderRadius: 64
  },
  imageContainer2: {

  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: thanks all the same but when I click the corner of the icon the button sill got highlighted.

Comment: React Native Playground is down now. I'd suggest putting up the example code on their new prototyping site, [sketch](https://sketch.expo.io/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an icon font, try this:

```html
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
        backgroundColor: '#108ee9',
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }}
>
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'YourIconFontFileName', fontSize: 24, color: '#279846'}}>&#xea45;{/*YourImageCode*/}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```