# Why does react-native border radius work on iOS but not Android Image

Tags: react-native

Created a list component, it has an image, some text, and a button. 
the image has a border radius and borderColor on it.

Problem: 
the colored-border-radius on android isn't being recognized, but on iOS it works fine...

here's the code:

List:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Modal,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
import { Svg, Path, G, Line } from 'react-native-svg';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const BlockList = (props) => {
    const onPress = (name) => {
        alert('Unblocking ' + name);
    };
    return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={props.data}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.leftSide}>
                        <Image source={item.img} style={styles.img} resizeMode={'contain'} />
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#454A66' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.rightSide}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item.name)} style={styles.btn}>
                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff' }}>Unblock</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )}
        />
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: width * 0.95,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        marginHorizontal: width * 0.025,
        marginBottom: width * 0.02,
        borderRadius: 18,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingVertical: width * 0.02,
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 3,
            height: 3
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 3,
        elevation: 5
    },
    img: {
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#219F75',
        height: width * 0.125,
        width: width * 0.125,
        marginHorizontal: width * 0.05
    },
    btn: {
        borderRadius: 11,
        backgroundColor: '#219F75',
        padding: width * 0.0275
    },
    leftSide: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    rightSide: {
        marginRight: width * 0.05
    }
});

export default BlockList;
```

here's what its supposed to look like (working correctly on iOS):
[image]

here's what is looks like on android (notice the square green border):
[image]

Why is this happening and how can I get my border radius?

Comment: Can you try adding overflow:'hidden' ?

Comment: Just did, no changes

Comment: @Jim can you share an expo snack for just 1 card with image so that i can check?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/Sk0GLqbg8

Comment: @Jim, when I remove the resizeMode, it works

Comment: @Lenoarod ahh brilliant. if you have any details or resources on why that happens, create an answer and ill award an answer

Comment: @Jim, I have updated my answer and explains why,  you can try it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if we want the view circle, we also realize it by setting the `borderRadius` equals half of the view height(width).

```
<View
   style={{
       borderWidth:1,
       borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
       alignItems:'center',
       justifyContent:'center',
       width:100,
       height:100,
       backgroundColor:'#fff',
       borderRadius:50,
     }}
 />
```

In your situation, your image sets the **resizeMode**. so it did not show the effect you want. for that try to move it in a view or use `resizeMode:stretch`; `resizeMode:cover` or remove it.

```
<View style={styles.leftSide}>
 <Image source={item.img} style={styles.img}/>
   <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#454A66' }}>{item.name}</Text>
 </View>

img: {
        borderRadius: width * 0.125*0.5,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#219F75',
        height: width * 0.125,
        width: width * 0.125,
        marginHorizontal: width * 0.05
    },
```

> contain: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: tried. again no changes. I dont think this has anything to do with the value of borderRadius

Comment: @Jim, try to set use the accrual number height and width to test. when makes a circle view by setting the border-radius equal half of the view height. the ios show maybe it happently equal.

Comment: you can see this answer link[https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580676/5705408] for some detail

Comment: **borderRadius value changes do not affect the desired outcome**

Comment: that because you set the image resize mode. which has scale it. try to make the image in a view

Comment: I had the similar issue the border radius was not getting applied in iOS but was working in android. Since I applied the border radius directly to Text control, it did work for android  but not for iOS then I moved the Text control inside the View and gave the style to View it worked just fine for both iOS and android.

Answer (score 0):

Try `borderRadius:width * 0.125` under img style.

Comment: Tried, No change

Answer (score 0):

You set image width height dynamically but border radius static value when using lower resolution device of android sometimes image borderRedius is larger to image width that's why it's occurred.

Please set all attribute dynamically. It will be better if use image borderRedius half of the width

Comment: Please read comments: **borderRadius value changes do not affect the desired outcome**

Answer (score 0):

**try this in img style** 
borderRadius: (width * 0.125)/2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the resizeMode to "cover"